# getting an average of a count of a group sql impala

Tags: sql, group-by, average, impala

Given a table like;

```
+----+----------+
| id | modality |
+----+----------+
| 1  | CT       |
| 1  | SC       |
| 1  | MR       |
| 1  | CT       |
| 2  | SC       |
| 3  | CT       |
| 3  | CT       |
| 3  | MR       |
| 4  | MR       |
| 4  | CT       |
+----+----------+
```

Something like;

```
SELECT AVG(modality_count) 
FROM (
SELECT id, COUNT(modality) AS modality_count
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY id
    ) a
```

Would get the average amount of modality per patient, and output something like:

```
+---------------------+
| AVG(modality_count) |
+---------------------+
| 1.4                 |
+---------------------+
```

the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(*) AS string), ' ' , modality) AS count_m
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY modality
```

would get the count of the number of rows for each modality, like:

```
+---+---------+
|   | count_m |
+---+---------+
| 1 | 560 CT  |
| 2 | 2 SC    |
| 3 | 473 MR  |
+---+---------+
```

Let's say there are 1035 rows, 726 unique ids, and each id is likely to have 1.4 scans (either CT, SC, MR). How would you get the average number of CT/ MT/ SC?

desired output something like:

```
+----------+---------+
| modality | AVG(id) |
+----------+---------+
| CT       | 0.77    |
| SC       | 0.003   |
| MR       | 0.65   |
+----------+---------+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain where 0.61 comes from?  I see 4 ids and 5 occurrences of CT on 3 of them.  I can understand 1.25 or 0.75.  But where does 0.61 come from?

Comment: My bad they are just example numbers, what I'm trying to obtain is the average number of CT, SC, MR for all the ids if that makes more sense? So given there are 726 unique ids, and 560 occurrences of CT, of the 1.42 scans each id is likely to have, there's a 0.77 chance that scan will be a CT. I've updated the op to reflect more sensible numbers.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can't you just make the example simple by sticking to the 10 sample rows you are showing first? What would be the numbers you expect in the result? Would the average amount of modality per patient be (4+1+3+2) / 4 = 2.5? And what would be the avarages per modality then?